# Compare date and time in SQL for DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I need to compare date and time of 2 fields and see if its greater than 24 hours however there is another field whose value is less than the 24 hours of the compared date. For example ,

- create date - 18/7/2019 11:15 AM
- target date - 19/07/2019 11:16 AM

There is a gap of 24 hours here

- Actual date - 19/07/2019 10:45 AM

Actual date is less than above said gap of 24 hours . Hence the query should return such records that has actual date less than the create date and target date gap of 24 hours. Here all the fields are of DATETIME data type in DB2 database.

Comment: Have you tried the [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000861.html) function?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein yes I had tried something like TIMESTAMPDIFF(8, CHAR(TIMESTAMP(targstartdate) - TIMESTAMP(createdate))) ='24' however I'm not sure on how to compare this gap with the actual date.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you really try to do.
`Actual date is less than above said gap of 24 hours`
How can a date may be comparable to a gap (or time duration)?
Should we understand it as:
`Gap between actual and created is less than gap between target and created`?
If so, then try the following:

```
select *
from 
(
select create, target, actual
, timestampdiff(8, char(target - create)) gap_target
, timestampdiff(8, char(actual - create)) gap_actual
from table(values 
  (timestamp('2019-07-18-11.15.00'), timestamp('2019-07-19-11.16.00'), timestamp('2019-07-19-10.45.00'))
) t (create, target, actual)
) 
where 
gap_target >= 24 and gap_actual < 24
-- or some another expression like:
-- gap_actual < gap_target
;  

CREATE              TARGET              ACTUAL              GAP_TARGET GAP_ACTUAL
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
2019-07-18 11:15:00 2019-07-19 11:16:00 2019-07-19 10:45:00         24         23
```

Is this what you want?
If not, then provide a few number of input records and the exact result desired.

Comment: `TIMESTAMPDIFF` can only return an estimate, due to the fact that the timestamp subtraction returns a relative period (although unless the times are local in a zone with DST, it's not going to make a difference for the listed time range.  DST would screw everything up, though).  This should be achievable with a range query on a modified `create` date, though, no need for `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.